# Where is the generic plan stored when using PREPARE statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-internals, prepared-statement

According to the [document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-prepare.html), *if a prepared statement is executed enough times, the server may eventually decide to save and re-use a generic plan rather than re-planning each time*. My question is where the generic plan is saved? Is it stored in a file in disk? If yes, where is it located and what is the file name?

Comment: I would guess that it's stored in memory.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You would guess correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic plan is stored in the in-memory plan cache of the back-end that created the plan. See [doxygen for `plancache.c`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/plancache_8c.html) or [the source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/cache/plancache.c).

Plans are not written to disk or read from disk, and are not shared between different backends (therefore, different sessions/connections). The documentation should really read:

> if a prepared statement is executed enough times *in a single session*, the server may eventually decide to save and re-use a generic plan *in the per-connection plan cache* rather than re-planning each time

You could probably modify the plancache code to serialize plans to disk, but it's not a trivial job to do it in a useful way. Reading them in on another backend *correctly* is much, much harder, when you consider the consequences of transactional DDL. Writing a proper persistent plan cache with correct plan invalidation etc would be a major job for an experienced PostgreSQL developer who already knew the optimizer/executor/planner/rewriter code well. If you wanted to tackle this you should expect to spend months studying the code before you could propose a reasonable approach, let alone implement it. (I've just been doing that with row-security for the [AXLE project](http://axleproject.eu), so I'm all too aware of the complexity of this code).

As I said in your last question, [let go of the idea that you can save plans, you can't, and concentrate on sorting out the issue that's causing the wrong plan to be chosen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/58414/7788).

Comment: I love all of your answers Craig. You rock.